# Determine coplanar (or collinear) points in higher dimensions with Java

Tags: java, vector, geometry

In Java, what is the best way to determine if a point (of which I have many) given in 6 dimensions lies on the same plane as other points in a 6-dimensional space? It's clear how to do that in 2D and 3D, but as far as I know some of the concepts such as cross product, etc, do not generalise to higher dimensions (or only to a specific few).

It would also be helpful to find a way to answer the same question for points on lines in 6D. More general, I have given a higher dimensional point cloud and I want to determine if some of these points lie on the same plane.

Comment: What do you mean by "plane" in 6-dimensional space?  When we say "plane" in 3-space, we are talking about a 2D linear subspace which also happens to be a (3-1)D linear subspace.  So, when you say "plane" in six dimensions, are you talking about a 2D subspace? or are you talking about a (6-1)D subspace (a.k.a., a "hyperplane")?

Comment: @jameslarge In the realm of this specific question, I was referring to the 2D linear subspace. But I would be equally interested in answering the question for any of the possible hyperplanes in this 6-dimensional case.

Comment: @Denor is your 6D space orthogonal/orthonormal? if not then the standard concepts does not apply (for example if you are mixing spatial and angular dimensions together or have curved/nonlinear axises) in some cases you can achieve transformation between closest orthonormal space and compute things there but usually that loose information (like point orientation)

Comment: @Spektre The space I am working in is essentially like `R^6`, thus orthonormal.

Comment: @Denor in that case all is fine and both answers are relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In N-dimensional space, point lies in the same hyperplane as N (non-degenerate) others, if volume of simplex, formed by all these (N+1) points, is zero. Simplex volume could be calculated through determinant

```
          |1 x1 y1 z1 ...|
          |1 x2 y2 z2 ...|
V = 1/N! |1 x3 y3 z3 ...|
          |1 x4 y4 z4 ...|
          |..............|
```

Note that this formula corresponds to cross product check for collinearity in 2D case, to mixed product check for coplanarity in 3D case etc

Comment: Great, that makes sense. As for the determinant calculation itself, does that mean I just construct a square matrix out of the points I would like to test by having each row represent one point and add a first column of "1s"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And you don't need `1/N!` term to check coplanarity.

Comment: One last question - what exactly makes it necessary to have the "1s" in there?

Comment: One may consider simplex volume as determinant of nxn matrix, created from n n-dimensional vectors (Vi-V0) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume . This (n+1)x(n+1) determinant is just an equivalent formula, alternative representation (shorter to write)

Comment: Hi everyone, I want to be sure I get this answer, does this mean for example to check if points in the fourth dimension (N=4) are for example co-cubic (asper collinear -> 1D plane,  coplanar -> 2D  plane ...). I take the determinant of the points with leading 1s and check if it's  = 0

Comment: @LiNKeR Yes, exactly.

Comment: Hi again, suppose one wants to get the volume of a 2-simplex having 3D vertices for example, how does one adapt the formula above to do that or say we limit ourselves to N=3 since the answer dots on afterwards, the formula above could be considered as calculation for a 3-simplex with 3D vertices but what if it gets rotated into a higher dimension such that the vertices become say 4D while still being a 3-simplex, what does one do?

Answer (score 1):

Classic equation on line, regardless of the dimensions, is:

```
x/const1 + y/const2 + ... + z/const3 = CONST0
```

By 2 points you always can find this equation:

```
(x - x1) / (x1 - x2) + (y - y1) / (y1 - y2) + ... + (z - z1) / (z1 - z2) = 0
```